# How to make debug build of specific module under AOSP tree?

Tags: android-ndk, android-source

I built eng flavor of AOSP tree and installed on a device. I like to step through code of a module (say libinput.so). I want to build this module with "-O0 -g" passed as part of CFLAGS. BUT I don't want to change the Android.mk file of this module.

Lets say this module is at aosppath/frameworks/base/service/input.
I cd to this folder after sourcing build/envsetup.sh.

I tried "**mm -B LOCAL_STRIP_MODULE=false**". When I was stepping through eclipse gdb, I see the execution order going zig zag. 
Then I tried "**mm -B LOCAL_STRIP_MODULE=false LOCAL_CFLAGS="-O0 -g"**"
Now gdb was able to step through fine. But this doesn't seem to work in other projects. I have a module that uses skia and opengl. The build is failing when I pass LOCAL_CFLAGS on command line.

What is the suggested way to make debug flavor of specific .so or exe under AOSP tree?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to change the .mk file? This is typically where you would set build type conditionals.

Comment: If I change .mk file, then I have to remember that I shouldn't check them in.

Answer (score 1):

So since the main reason you don't want to make changes to Android.mk is so you don't have to check it in, an alternative here is to use the .repo/local_manifests folder to change a module that is owned by android to be owned by you.

Here is a sample my_manifest.xml file which can do this for you:

```
<manifest>
  <remote name="origin"
           fetch="ssh://git@github.com/YourRepoHere/" />

  <remove-project name="platform/frameworks/base"/>
  <project path="frameworks/base" remote="origin" name="frameworks-base" revision="your-branch-name"/>

</manifest>
```

This will remove frameworks/base from the android manifest tree, and replace it with your own manifest tree (which you need to fork into your own repository).

After that, you can then use a conditional inside of your Android.mk file like so:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT),userdebug)
    CONDITIONAL_CHANGES_HERE
endif
```

Again, I realize that you didn't want to modify the Android.mk file but since you also asked for the suggested way of making a module that is conditional on the build variant, I am going to include this answer anyway in case nothing better comes your way. This is really the suggested way of doing what you want to do, as your project will now be maintained by the repo tool.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This seems pretty involving. I am expecting something along the lines of "mm DEBUG=true" that results in CFLAGS with right debug values. Isn't there trick like that?

Comment: Well it seems like the way you are calling it is fine, since STRIP_MODULE appears to work for you. That would imply that you can set env variables throught the mm command, is it possible that the Android.mk file is redefining or changing the LOCAL_CFLAGS on it's own?

Comment: external/skia folder is the one that fails when I pass LOCAL_CFLAGS as part of mm. I searched all the .mk files. I don't see LOCAL_CFLAGS:= type assignments anywhere. All are += type assignments which are expected.

Comment: Ah yes but see it includes the line: include $(CLEAR_VARS). If you go and look at clear_vars.mk in build/core you will see that LOCAL_CFLAGS gets cleared as part of this definition. I'm curious as to whether this would break your attempts when passing in the variable through mm, though I don't know why the STRIP_MODULE would have made any change

Comment: Most of the .mk files have this include at the top. I don't think it affects the vars that are passed from command line. The modules that build fine have this include at the top as well.

Comment: Have you tried using the -e / --environment-overrides options and setting all the environment variables you require manually with export?